# wherePivot group priorities (and/or)

Tags: laravel

I have troubles making a wherePivot and/or priority work.

Let me explain with code.

I have 3 tables:

product

- id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT
- product VARCHAR(255)

client

- id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT
- client VARCHAR(255)

client_product

- client_id UNSIGNED INTEGER
- product_id UNSIGNED INTEGER
- price DECIMAL(9,2) NULL
- valid_from (DATETIME) NULL
- valid_until (DATETIME) NULL

I'd like to find the price for a product for a client for a specific date.

I have a scope in Product model:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'client_product', 'product_id', 'client_id')
        ->withPivot('price', 'valid_from', 'valid_until');
}
```

If the product has a price, then:

- valid_from has a date set and cannot be null.
- valid_until can be null or have a date set

To get the price for a product, I tried these 2 functions on the Product model but none works:

```
public function findPrice($clientId, $date)
{
    return $this->clients()
        ->where('client_id', $clientId)
        ->where('valid_from', '<=', $date)
        ->where(function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->wherePivot('valid_until', '>=', $date)
              ->orWherePivot('valid_until', '=', NULL);
        })
        ->first();
}
```

I get this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                  
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause'
```

Also, I can't use

```
public function findPrice($clientId, $date)
{
    return $this->clients()
        ->where('client_id', $clientId)
        ->where('valid_from', '<=', $date)
        ->wherePivot(function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->where('valid_until', '>=', $date)
              ->orWhereNull('valid_until');
        })
        ->first();
}
```

I get this error:

```
[ErrorException]                                          
Object of class Closure could not be converted to string
```

as the 'wherePivot' method only takes a string as a first argument and not a Closure as the 'where' method

```
BelongsToMany wherePivot(string $column, string $operator = null, mixed $value = null, string $boolean = 'and')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it without wherePivot, just use the where() in query and specifiy your middle table name with column name so in where clause it will consider column to be on middle table for ex.

```
public function findPrice($clientId, $date)
{
    return $this->clients()
        ->where('client_id', $clientId)
        ->where('valid_from', '<=', $date)
        ->where(function($query) use ($date) {
            $query->where('client_product.valid_until', '>=', $date)
              ->orWhere('client_product.valid_until', '=', NULL);
        })
        ->first();
}
```

consider where client_product.valid_until

this should work and filter will apply on middle table.

Comment: mark the answer as correct if it's working, so other users can get reference about that.. :)